# path differences in netbeans, cmd, and .bat or .cmd

Tags: java, windows, path, batch-file, cmd

I am facing a strange issue. My code runs just fine from Netbeans or cmd with

```
java -jar MP2.jar
```

but when I try to run it from the .bat or .cmd

```
"%JAVA_HOME%"\bin\java -jar .. \dist\MP2.jar > test_mp2_out.txt
```

I get an error in my text file

```
DataIn\nrmavg.txt (The System cannot find the path specified)
```

or a null pointer exception at the line I have new FileReader(nrmavg.txt)

I can provide more code if needed, but I think this may be a windows problem.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think FileReader("nrmavg.txt") won't be looking for a file inside .jar, just a current directory. Could you try using something like this instead?

```
InputStream is = MP2.class.getResourceAsStream("nrmavg.txt") ;
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
```

Comment: BTW my DataIn folder is in the Netbeans Project folder, as is the dist folder that holds MP2.jar , and the test folder that holds the .bat .

Comment: But your .bat file is executed from somewhere else, isn't it? and that becomes the current folder where Runtime tries to locate nrmavg.txt. As alternative, you can try changing your .bat to CD to your DataIn folder.

Comment: Yes, and so this code .. \dist\MP2.jar backs up a dir and executes the jar. the jar is executing but throwing a null pointer error if called from the .bat . If I cd into the dist dir that holds the jar and execute it from cmd directly it runs as expected. It runs in netbeans as expected.

Comment: @jeremyjjbrown The option "-jar ..\dist\MP2.jar" tells JVM where to find the jar file. It is still executed in the dir where your .bat file is. Since nrmavg.txt is not in this current directory it fails to locate it. So, option A) cd to the dist dir as Ernesto is saying, option B) add dist dir to the classpath and use getResource... method to have JVM search for it.

Answer (score 0):

Is Netbeans creating a directory called *lib* on your *dist* directory? If yes, maybe it is unreacheable for Java. Could you try the following in your *cmd* file:

```
cd PROJECT_FOLDER\dist
"%JAVA_HOME%"\bin\java -jar MP2.jar > test_mp2_out.txt
```

Where PROJECT_FOLDER is the Netbeans project folder.